# dovecot unable to locate dkim plugin

Tags: ubuntu, postfix-mta, dovecot, opendkim

In my mail.log file I get this error.

Error: Plugin 'dkim' not found from directory /usr/lib/dovecot/modules

I can't figure it out and cant find any relevant information anywhere.

Tried checking the conf files to see if I could change where it should look for the file. I couldn't find anything like that and even if I did I don't know where it would be if its not in the correct directory.